# Count the number of “trues” for n booleans

Tags: java

```
public static boolean StarTrack[][][] = {
  {{true,true,true}, {true,true,true}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}},
  {{false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}},
  {{false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}},
  {{false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}, {false,false,false}, {false,false,false},
   {false,false,false}}
};
```

I want to know how to count the number of trues in that array using java. "I have this array and I want to count the number of trues. How can I do this?"

Comment: You can do this , by using loops and if condition

Comment: I wouldn't say this question is "unclear" - seems pretty clear to me that the OP wants to know how to count the number of trues in that array using java. "I have this array and I want to count the number of trues. How can I do this?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, you could with this -

```
int count = 0;
for (boolean[][] bArrArr : StarTrack) {
    for (boolean[] bArr : bArrArr) {
        for (boolean b : bArr) {
            if (b) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Given your `StarTrack` I get the output of

```
6
```

Comment: as per your code b is coming false always?

Comment: @swap No. It's true 6 times, given `StarTrack` above.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is 3-Dimensional, you can try using 3 `for` loops:

```
int count = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < StarTrack.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < StarTrack[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < StarTrack[i][j].length; k++) {
            if (StarTrack[i][j][k]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(count); // 6
```

Note that

```
if (StarTrack[i][j][k])
```

will check if the value of the element of the array `StarTrack[i][j][k]` is `true`. If it is, increase `count`.

**An alternative**, in order to avoid using indexes, is to use `foreach` loops:

```
for (boolean[][] array2D: StarTrack) {
    for (boolean[] array1D : bArrArr) {
        for (boolean element : bArr) {
            if (element) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```